# How to make Google Closure Compiler understand the `caches` variable (CacheStorage)?

Tags: service-worker, google-closure-compiler, cachestorage

If I use `caches` in my service worker code then Google Closure Compiler (launched with the advanced optimizations mode) will tell me :

> /var/www/html/perso/otraSite/web/js/sw_viaTypescript.js:79: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] > variable caches is undeclared
>   })(caches);
>      ^^^^^^
>
> 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

A workaround that I use until now is ... I put `window.caches` so Google Closure Compiler succeeds to compile but if I let that code, browsers will tell me :

> sw.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

So I replace `window.caches` by `caches` in the code compiled by Google Closure Compiler afterwards but ... having to do this every single time is pretty annoying.

Is there a cleaner way to handle it?

Comment: This sounds like `caches` is being renamed by the compiler and therefore isn't defined when you load it with your worker, but its a bit hard to tell from this amount of information. If that's the case, then use externs: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Comment: Externs is for variables declared from our JavaScript files... `caches` is a navigator "thing" so I do not see why I would have to declare it, for example, I do not declare `window`... I have an inline javascript in my HTML that load my file `sw.js` (via `e.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js")`) where there is a self executing function that ends like that `})(caches);`.